# Assignment to slots with inequality constraints

Tags: mathematical-optimization, constraint, discrete

Suppose that I have a table `A` with each of its n columns corresponding to an "individual" and each of its m rows corresponding to a "task". The element of the jth row and ith column,  s(ji), is a real number, which can be interpreted as a score measuring the quality of match between individual i and task j.

A second table, `B` has n columns and two rows. The first row of column i specifies the maximum number of tasks that individual i can be assigned to. The second row specifies the minimum number of tasks that individual i can be assigned to (the two values might be equal).

A third table, `C` has m columns and two rows. The first row of column j specifies the maximum number of individuals that task j can be assigned to. The second row specifies the minimum number of individuals that task j can be assigned to (the two values might be equal).

The elements of B and C are natural numbers.

I would like to output an n column, m row table with element I(ji) equal to 1 if individual i is assigned to task j and zero otherwise, such that the constraints given in the second and third tables are satisfied and the output maximises the total score,

$$\sum_{i,j}I_{ij}s_{ji}.$$

As an example, suppose we have the following input:

```
A={{5,3},{1,2}}
B={{1,1},{1,0}}
C={{1,1},{1,1}}
```

Table `A` says, for instance, that individual 1 has a score of 5 for task 1 and 1 for task 2. Table `B` says that individual 1 should be assigned exactly 1 task, while individual 2 should be assigned between 0 and 1 tasks. Table `C` says each task should have no less than one individual and no more than one individual assigned. The solution (and desired output) is

```
{{1,0},{0,1}}
```

i.e. we assign individual 1 to task 1 and individual 2 to task 2 because that maximises the score (5+2) subject to the constraints. While we could get a higher score by, for example, giving task 1 to both individuals (total score is then `5+3`), this would violate the constraint in `C`.

This is for practical use, so a numerical approach that finds an approximately correct solution would also be fine. If there is a more convenient way to supply the scores/constraints then that is also fine.

I have no idea how to even start programming this in Mathematica. Is anyone able to offer any direction?

Comment: your terminology is unclear, what do you mean by "slot"? "individual"? Maybe a small example would be useful.  `Slot` has a specific meaning in mathematica by the way: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Slot.html  I assume that's not what you mean.

Comment: @george2079 I have added an example and switched the term slot for task. I also edited the first paragraph a little to try to be clearer that the terminology "individual" and "task" are just arbitrary lables for the two entities I want to assign to one another in the (constrained) optimal fashion.

Comment: related: [Efficient solution for a discrete assignment problem with pairwise costs](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/88118/125)

Comment: see also: [FindMaximumFlow](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FindMaximumFlow.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a = {{5, 3}, {1, 2}}
b = {{1, 1}, {1, 0}}
c = {{1, 1}, {1, 1}}
```

some functions to check the criteria:

```
c1[result_] := 
 And @@ Table[ 
   c[[i, 1]] >= Total@result[[All, i]] >= c[[i, 2]]  , {i, 
    Length@result[[1]]}]
c2[result_] := 
 And @@ Table[ 
   b[[i, 1]] >= Total@result[[i]] >= b[[i, 2]]  , {i, Length@result}]
```

and calculate the score:

```
score[result_] := Total@MapThread[ Dot, { a, result }]
```

check:

```
result={{1,0},{0,1}}
c1[result] (*True*)
c2[result] (*True*)
score[result, a] (* 7 *)
```

now for this small problem `NMaximise` gets the solution..
( same approach as here https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/88226/2079 with different constraints )

create an `result` array:

```
result = Array[ v , {2, 2}]
unknowns = Flatten@result

NMaximize[{score[result], 
  c1[result] && c2[result] && 
   And @@ (0 <= # <= 1 & /@ Flatten[result])} , unknowns , Integers ]
```

> {7., {v[1,1] -> 1, v[1,2] -> 0, v[2,1] -> 0, v[2,2] -> 1}}

```
result /. %[[2]]
```

> {{1, 0}, {0, 1}}

Comment: Thanks, this is great! With a few tweaks it works for arbitrary m and n.